# Android error - dlopen - cannot locate symbol but only on Nexus

Tags: android, c++, native, dlopen

So, my game runs fine on several devices including Samsung Galaxy S4 and the NVIDIA Shield. But on Nexus 7 (and 5 have the symptoms on a colleague's device, but I haven't been able to confirm through the debugger).

The game consists of 14 shared native libraries plus main.so, all written in C++ and they all seem to load fine, except at least one of in house custom built libraries fails the symbol lookup when instantiating a class, but only when running on a Nexus.

One other symptom is that things seem to work fine if I inline the method that fails the symbol lookup in the header file (as opposed to being in the .cpp file). In this case, the failed symbol lookup just moved to other methods defined in the cpp file (I haven't tried moving everything into the header yet).

I have manually checked that the .so actually has the missing symbol, so I am sure the method is there. The missing symbol is in the libinput.so shown as loaded below.

I have pasted the last part of the log including callstack below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have looked around, and no questions I could find seemed to share exactly my symptoms..

... < cut out dynamic loads for other libraries similar to the below > ...

```
06-15 23:42:37.155: D/dalvikvm(11695): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.kotoristudios.MULEReturns-1/libinput.so 0x41e1dd58
06-15 23:42:37.155: D/dalvikvm(11695): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.kotoristudios.MULEReturns-1/libinput.so 0x41e1dd58
06-15 23:42:37.155: D/dalvikvm(11695): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.kotoristudios.MULEReturns-1/libinput.so 0x41e1dd58, skipping init
```

... < cut out dynamic loads for other libraries similar to the above > ...

```
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/dalvikvm(11695): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.kotoristudios.MULEReturns-1/libmain.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN5Input12InputManager13ReceiveEventsERSt6vectorIPNS_5EventESaIS3_EE" referenced by "libmain.so"...
06-15 23:42:37.185: W/dalvikvm(11695): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/kotoristudios/MULEReturns/MULEReturnsActivity;
06-15 23:42:37.185: W/dalvikvm(11695): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/kotoristudios/MULEReturns/MULEReturnsActivity;)
06-15 23:42:37.185: D/AndroidRuntime(11695): Shutting down VM
06-15 23:42:37.185: W/dalvikvm(11695): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4154bba8)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695): Process: com.kotoristudios.MULEReturns, PID: 11695
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN5Input12InputManager13ReceiveEventsERSt6vectorIPNS_5EventESaIS3_EE" referenced by "libmain.so"...
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at com.kotoristudios.MULEReturns.MULEReturnsActivity.(MULEReturnsActivity.java:28)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-15 23:42:37.185: E/AndroidRuntime(11695):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 23:47:37.408: I/Process(11695): Sending signal. PID: 11695 SIG: 9
```